# Cabinet to conceal dryer hose -- okay to mount just to floor and ceiling?

Tags: cabinets, closet, laundry, built-ins

first time attempting a built-in of any kind.

We have this unattractive space next to our stacked washer/dryer and I'd like to fill it with a built-in cabinet -- drawers on the bottom, shelves up top. Here's my problem:

First, I need to leave space for the dryer hose, which means I can't run the cabinet all the way to the back of the closet. (I'm planning to attach a false back to the cabinet with magnets so I can still access the vent if necessary)

Second, the closet wall isn't flush with the door frame. It indents about six inches. That means I can't build the cabinet up against the side wall, because otherwise I wouldn't be able to open the drawers.

As such, my current plan is to attach the cabinet only at the floor and ceiling, but I'm worried that this would look weird/be unsafe. A second option would be for me to build the cabinet so that it could hook into the door frame itself, but then the cabinet would be attached to the frame only at the front edge.

I've attached a picture of the current space so you can have some idea of what I'm working with. Any advice would be very much appreciated.

[image: Empty closet next to stacked washer/dryer]

Comment: However you mount it, two considerations: make it removable so it does not block access to the vent hose, which should be cleaned regularly, and **don't block airflow to prevent overheating the appliances**.

Comment: I plan to make the back removable so I can still access the vent.

Comment: Accessing the back on occasion is one thing. Allowing regular airflow for day-to-day operations of the dryer is another and what I think @DrMoishePippik is suggesting. I'd suggest that you'll want to use the toe-kick area under the bottom cabinet for either a full opening or put a vent grate over it, then make sure that the back is open. At the top, leave another opening, too. This will allow convective air flow drawing cooler air in the bottom and allowing hotter air to exhaust at the top, preventing the build up of hot air behind the cabinet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest buying/building cabinets that will fit the opening between the washer/dryer stack and the opening in the wall.

Then, build a framework out of 2x4 or other suitable lumber that will fit in behind the bit of wall behind the door opening, creating a snug fit between the closet wall and the to-be-installed cabinetry. Attach this framework to the closet wall, then attach the cabinets to it. This will provide you a nice secure installation for your cabinetry, while allowing full opening of drawers and doors.

---

As noted in a comment, you don't want to completely seal off the area preventing airflow into and out of the closet. Trapping all the hot air from the dryer back there could, at a minimum, be detrimental to the lifespan of the appliances, and could, at worst, start a fire in any lint that may be in the dryer vent or that may escape the vent through a leak. I'd recommend a vent in the toe-kick at the bottom of the cabinet stack to allow cooler air to enter at ground level, then a vent at the top above the stack of cabinets to allow warmer air to escape. Leave some space behind the cabinets to allow this airflow. Depending on how tight the fit is to the washer/dryer stack and how much ventilation room there is around the stack vs the rest of the closet, this may not be necessary.

---

Thinking to the future, you might want to buy/build cabinets that are a few inches *narrower* than the space you have available. You'd fill the gap between the cabinets and the washer/dryer stack (if that's your plan) with a blanking panel screwed into the sides of the cabinet face frames. In the future, when (not if) this set dies or you simply want to replace with something newer, you'll have a few additional inches of space to replace them with physically larger units if you desire or that's all that's available.

Comment: I really like this approach and it's probably what I'll end up doing. Thanks in particular for the advice on venting — do you think six inches of space top and bottom will be enough?. The cabinets definitely won't go all the way to the back of the closet (the stacked laundry unit doesn't go that far back either). Lastly, any advice on attaching the framework?

Comment: Attach the framework with screws, @AndrewSanders. That way you can remove it _easily_ if/when you decide you don't like it anymore/it's not working for you/new washer dryers don't stack, whatever. Nails are fine, but they're a _lot_ harder to remove neatly.

Comment: Also, @AndrewSanders, if you'll take the [tour], you'll note that the proper way to say "thanks" or "I really like this" is to click the up arrow next to _any and all_ answers that you find helpful. In another day or so (giving time for others to chime in with ideas), click the check mark next to the answer that helped you _the most_.

Comment: Additionally, I'd suggest making an opening that you can cover with something like a standard 4x10 or so heating duct grill (pick a grill size, shape and pattern that suits you and/or other house residents). You'd probably want 2 each at the top & bottom. Note that the supply grills for a forced hot air system are much smaller than the passive return air grills. Since this is a passive system, I'd err on the side of larger is better.

Answer (score 1):

For what it's worth this was my solution to the identical situation.  I bought a stacked (not stacking) machine with zero-clearance at the rear and a side vent (you can barely see behind the vacuum at the bottom).  This allowed me to use doors instead of a curtain.

I used wall shelves on the recessed wall to the left to maximize storage and access to it, allowing room for taller things in the (very limited) gap between, allowing access to the side and rear of the machine if needed.

And I put LED strip lighting on the back side of the door because it's a deep closet full of stuff so this way I can see and reach everything.

[image]